# How to get Win-Key + Space to switch languages working again?

Tags: windows-10, language-bar

I am using Windows 10 Pro and have three languages installed for typing that I always switch between by pressing the Windows key and the space bar.

I just noticed that it is not working anymore. I have no idea what has caused this change, and I do not know when my last Windows update occured. But I would find it very strange for such an update to remove this suddenly, since tons of previous updates did not remove this shortcut.

I also noticed that there used to be an icon indicating the current language input which is gone now. So I think that this might be the real reason for why the shortcut is not working anymore.
But I have checked and done all of these things below and it is still missing.

1. Different languages are installed
   [image: langs]
2. This checkbox is checked
   [image]
3. This switch is on
   [image: List item]
4. The radio button group has the 'docked in taskbar' value
   [image]
5. I restarted my computer

The language icon still nowhere to be found
[image: no language icon]

What else could I try?